# Inner join two list of list given indices

Tags: python, list, inner-join

What's the fastest way to inner join two list of lists given a set of indices?

Ex:

```
[[1,2,3],
[1,3,3],
[1,2,3]]

[[1,2,4],
[1,3,4],
[1,3,5]]
```

join if indices 0 and 1 match

Result:

```
[[1,2,3,4],
[1,3,3,4],
[1,3,3,5],
[1,2,3,4]]
```

The trivial method of implementing this seems to be too slow, what's the fastest way to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you can use `pandas` for that:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d0 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[1,3,3],[1,2,3]])
>>> d1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,4],[1,3,4],[1,3,5]])
>>> pd.merge(d0,d1, on=[0,1])
   0  1  2_x  2_y
0  1  2    3    4
1  1  2    3    4
2  1  3    3    4
3  1  3    3    5
```

which should do the job not too bad, as it's a scientific library designed for that. But as I don't know the source, I cannot tell its complexity.

```
>>> def test():
...   pd.merge(d0,d1, on=[0,1])
>>> timeit.timeit(test, number=1000)
1.9183850288391113
```

on my computer.